# Ajax doesn't get response from PHP side

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, jquery

Using ajax+php in my signup form. There are 2 validations: JS side frontend and PHP side backend. Created special function called `response` in PHP side: It sends PHP side error as JSON data.

**The problem is** I can't get any response from PHP side.

Analyzed page in firebug: getting error message `responseData is null`. (`responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data)`)

*JS part looks like that*

```
  //check the form is not currently submitting
  if ($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting') {

 var form = $(this),
    formData = form.serialize() + '&formID=' + form.attr('id'),
    formUrl = form.attr('action'),
    formMethod = form.attr('method');



 //add status data to form
 form.data('formstatus', 'submitting');

 if (validate()) {
    //send data to server for validation
    $.ajax({
       url: formUrl,
       type: formMethod,
       data: formData,
       success: function (data) {

          //setup variables
          var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data),
             cl, text;

          //response conditional
          switch (responseData.status) {
          case 'error':
             cl = 'error';
             text = responseData.message;
             break;
          case 'success':
             cl = 'success';
             text = 'Qeydiyyat uğurla başa çatdı';
             break;
          }


          $.notifyBar({
             cls: cl,
             html: text
          });

       }
    });

 }
 form.data('formstatus', 'idle');


 }
```

*And here is PHP part*

```
    <?php
require '../common.php';

function checkIfEmailExists($email, $stmt)
{
        if ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE email=? LIMIT 1")) {
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($count);
                $stmt->close();
        }

        return ($count > 0 ? true : false);
}


if ($_POST['formID'] == 'signup_form') {
        // Setting vars
        $lname        = $_POST['lname'];
        $fname        = $_POST['fname'];
        $mname        = $_POST['mname'];
        $email        = $_POST['email'];
        $pass         = $_POST['pass'];
        $confirm_pass = $_POST['confirm_pass'];

        //===================== 
        //Server side validation >>


        //First name, middle name, last name check >>
        if (!$lname) {
                response('error', 'Familiyanı daxil edin');
        }
        if (!$fname) {
                response('error', 'Adı daxil edin');
        }
        if (!$mname) {
                response('error', 'Atanızın adını daxil edin');
        }
        //<<

        //Pass check >>
        if (strlen($pass) > 2) {
                if ($pass == $confirm_pass) {
                        return true;
                } else {
                        response('error', 'Şifrənin təkrarlanmasında səhv');
                }
        } else {
                response('error', 'Şifrədə simvolların sayı 4-dən çox olmalıdır');
        }

        //<<


        //email validation >>
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                if (!checkIfEmailExists($email, $stmt)) {
                        return true;
                } else {
                        response('error', 'Bu ünvanla qeydiyyata alınmış başqa istifadəçi var.');
                }
        } else {
                response('error', 'Email ünvanını düzgün daxil edin');
        }

        //<<

        // Create statement object
        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();

        // Create a prepared statement
        if ($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`, `mname`, `lname`, `email`, `pass`, `reg_dt`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())")) {
                // Binding vars

                $rc = $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $fname, $lname, $mname, $email, $pass) or die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));

                // Execute query
                $rc = $stmt->execute();
                if ($rc) {
                        response('success', 'Qeydiyyat uğurla başa çatdı');
                } else {
                        response('error', htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                }


                // Close statement object
                $stmt->close();

        } else {
                response('error', htmlspecialchars($dv->error));
        }



}
else {response('error', 'Qeydiyyatda problem');}

        //return json response
        function response($status, $message)
        {
                $data = array(
                        'status' => $status,
                        'message' => $message
                );
                echo json_encode($data);
                die();
        }
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$_POST['formID'] == 'signup_form'`? It also looks like you have some `return true;` calls spread through there rather than printing something or just continuing on.

Comment: `Analyzed page in firebug: getting error message responseData is null. (responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data))` … That doesn't mean you aren't getting a response. What is `data`? Is it empty?

Comment: Tried to simply check whether your script responses anything by adding `echo "test";` below your include for example?

Comment: Is $_POST['formID'] == 'signup_form'?

Comment: @Quentin data is response from PHP

Comment: @Tural Teyyuboglu — Yes, but what does it contain? Is it empty? Is it a string? Is it invalid JSON?

Comment: Please take a look at PHP part `function response($status, $message) {...`

Comment: @Jeune i have else statement too

Comment: @Tural Teyyuboglu — Not "what does it theoretically contain", what does it **actually** contain when you debug it?

Comment: @Sn0opy You mean in php code? i have both if else statements, it, must response something in any case

Comment: @Quentin Tried alert(data); in success function. It gives null.

Comment: @jprofitt  i have both if else statements, it, must response something in any case. I guess it's the problem of JS side

Comment: Yes, but there is a path in both of them that is simply `return true;` rather than echoing anything.

Comment: I have taken AJAX totally. Posting directly to php from form. There is no error in php errors log, and no success. It doesn't give any error message, just blank screen, (but as you see from code i'm validating variables in every step ) what it can be? I guess it's not JS related problem.

Comment: Please, do what I'm about to suggest because you have been skipping over some very helpful comments. Add an `echo 'in if';` right after your `if($_POST['formId'] == 'signup_form']){...` and replace `return true;` with `echo 'true';` in both if statements. View it again as a standalone script. If you still get nothing printed out after you submit the form then there is an issue with something else.

Comment: Have fixed some php side wrongs. Turned off all ajax, testing just php.  Now getting output like that: {"status":"error","message":"error msg"} Is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
dataType: "json",
```

In your $.Ajax method.

Comment: Try alert(data); into success function. What it gives?

Comment: try do do some debugging. Try to output something from your php-script to make sure the javascript is not the problem. if the javascript get the debug-response, this is a php-related error somewhere in your script

Comment: I didn't downvote:) @OptimusCrime  i have both if else statements, it, must response something in any case

Comment: @OptimusCrime also i tried to remove the submit function and to post data directly to php. It gave me message. PHP side works

Comment: alert your all variables in jquery formData, formUrl and formMethod and make shure that they are getting right value.

Comment: what result do you get if you simply dump your $_POST in the php-file? Are the post-variables sent with ajax? `echo json_encode($_POST);` try that in your script

Comment: I have taken AJAX totally. Posting directly to php from form. There is no error in php errors log, and no success. It doesn't give any error message, just blank screen, (but as you see from code i'm validating variables in every step ) what it can be?  I guess it's not JS related problem.