# jQuery AJAX gets no response from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

When I try to make jQuery AJAX requests in PHP, I have several issues. What's the problem with my simple example?

`index.php` - loading JS, PHP and defining a button and a paragraph.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='jquery-3.0.0.js'></script>
        <script src='main.js'></script>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="action" onClick="Send()">Send data</button>
        <p id="result"></p>

        <?php require('main.php'); ?>                   
    </body>
</html>
```

`main.js` - it contains the function associated to the 'onClick' event.

```
function Send(){        
    $.ajax({
        url: 'main.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            input: "test",
            message: "Sending..."
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {               
            alert(data);                
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "DONE!";          
        }       
    }); 
}
```

main.php - it listens to POST requests, and sends back a JSON.

```
<?php
if ($_POST){        
    // Make a array with the values
    $vals = [
        'input'     => $input,
        'message'   => $message
    ];

    echo json_encode($vals);
}
```

The `success` callback runs, but the `alert` message is entirely empty. `alert(data.input)` shows `undefined`.

It is clear that no data is sent back to the AJAX request. How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm sure this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050709/ajax-doesnt-get-response-from-php-side?rq=1

Comment: Dont think this is actually your problem, but you are passing data between 2 programs. You dont need the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

Comment: So have you looked at the contents of `data` using the browsers javascript debugger

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you explain, how can I do it?

Comment: F12 will load the developer console

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know, I'm using that but how can I check the content of `data` there? The only method I know for it is `console.log`

Comment: Its a debugger. Put a breakpoint on the `alert()` line

Comment: @RiggsFolly [Done! And "data" is empty.](http://i.imgur.com/R5y3XZ4.png?1) Even worse if I add `datatype: 'json'` to the AJAX request, `success` doesn't even run then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're not sending response from PHP as JSON.

Add following line above `echo json_encode()`;

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

So your PHP code will look something like this,

```
<?php
if ($_POST){        
    // Make a array with the values
    $vals = array(
        'input'     => $input,
        'message'   => $message
    );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');      
    echo json_encode($vals, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);     // Now we want to JSON encode these values to send them to $.ajax success.
    exit;                                           // to make sure you aren't getting nothing else
}
?>
```

Also as @Ismail mentioned `dataType : 'json'` add this in `.AJAX` call to accept JSON response from API.

Comment: I have never had to use the `header()` you suggest so I dont think its actually necessary

Comment: @RiggsFolly the header will help jQuery automatically recognize the data type.

Comment: Not sure, I faced similar issue earlier so thought this might fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

in main_js.js

```
function Send(){
    var data_JSON = {
        input: "test",
        message: "Sending..."
    };          
    $.ajax({
        url: 'main_php.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data_JSON,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){                
            if(response.type == "success")               
            {
                 alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                 alert(response.data.input);
                 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  response.message;          
            }
            else
            {
                 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response.message;          
            }

        }       
    }); 
}
```

in php code

```
<?php
$response= array();
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){        
    // Make a array with the values
    $vals = $_POST;      
    $response['data']=json_encode($vals);     // Now we want to JSON     
    $response["type"]="success";
    $response["message"]="Successfully posted";
}
else
{
    $response=array(
       "type"=>"error",
       "message"=>"invalid post method"
    );
}
ob_clean();
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: also you can use in alert(data.input) in if condition.

Comment: Done, it says "ERROR!", but not only when I click on the button, but also prints out the error message to the bottom of the HTML. Not sure if it's right.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.